# android-login button-click-application has stopped

Tags: android, button, authentication

I'm new to android, I have no idea why when I clicks the LOGIN button in my apps, it show Application has stopped.I have checked my coding many times but i still dunno where is the problems, could anyone teach me ? I'm willing to learn :) (ps:another button , sign up button works well)

This is the main_activity.java

```
    Button b1,b2;
    EditText ed1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

     public void onButtonClick(View v){

        b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.blogin);
        b2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bsignup);
        ed1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.EVPassword);

                 if (v.getId() == R.id.blogin)
                {
                    EditText a = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ETmatrix);
                    String str = a.getText().toString();
                     ed1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.EVPassword);
                    String pass = ed1.getText().toString();
                    String password = helper.searchPass(str);

                    if(pass.equals(password))
                    {
                        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, HomePage.class);
                        i.putExtra("matrix", str);
                        startActivity(i);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast temp = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Matrix No. & Password does not match!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        temp.show();
                    }
                }
                if (v.getId() == R.id.bsignup )
                {
                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SignUp.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }



        }
        }
```

the main_activty.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/logo">


    <TextView android:text="Login" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textview"
    android:textSize="35dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Student Planner"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textview"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="30dp" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/matrix"
        android:hint="Matrix Number"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:textColorHighlight="#ff7eff15"
        android:textColorHint="#ffff25e6"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imageView" />

      <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/password"
          android:textColorHint="#ffff299f"
        android:hint="Password"
          android:layout_below="@+id/matrix"
          android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/matrix"
          android:layout_alignStart="@+id/matrix"
          android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
          android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="login"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:id="@+id/blogin"
        android:onClick="onButtonClick"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/bsignup"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/password"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/password" />

      <Button
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="Sign Up Here"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:id="@+id/bsignup"
          android:onClick="onButtonClick"
          android:layout_below="@+id/password"
          android:layout_alignRight="@+id/password"
          android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/password"
          android:layout_marginTop="55dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

the databasehelper.java

```
 private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "register.db";
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "register";
    private static final String COLUMN_ID = "id";
    private static final String COLUMN_UNAME = "uname";
    private static final String COLUMN_EMAIL = "email";
    private static final String COLUMN_PASS = "pass";
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    private static final String TABLE_CREATE = "create table register (id integer primary key not null ,"+
        "uname text not null,email text not null,pass text not null)";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context)
   {
       super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
   }

    private void OnCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(TABLE_CREATE);
        this.db = db;
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(TABLE_CREATE);
        this.db = db;
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
    {
        String query = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + TABLE_NAME;
        db.execSQL(query);
        this.OnCreate(db);
    }



    public void insertRegister(Register r)
    {
        db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values= new ContentValues();

        String query = "select * from register";
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query,null);
        int count = cursor.getCount();

        values.put(COLUMN_ID,count);
        values.put(COLUMN_UNAME,r.getUname());
        values.put(COLUMN_EMAIL,r.getEmail());
        values.put(COLUMN_PASS, r.getPass());

        db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
        db.close();
    }

    public String searchPass(String uname)
    {
        db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        String query = "select uname, pass from "+TABLE_NAME;
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query , null);
        String a, b;
        b = "not found";
        if(cursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            do{
                a = cursor.getString(0);

                if(a.equals(uname))
                {
                    b = cursor.getString(1);
                    break;
                }
            }
            while(cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        return b;
    }





}
```

register.java

```
public class Register {

    String uname, email, pass;

   public void setUname(String uname) {this.uname = uname;}

    public String getUname() {
        return this.uname;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return this.email;
    }

    public void setPass(String pass) {
        this.pass = pass;
    }

    public String getPass() {
        return this.pass;
    }



}
```

logcat

```
12-05 23:29:02.604    7508-7508/? D/dalvikvm﹕ Late-enabling CheckJNI
12-05 23:29:02.628    7508-7514/? D/dalvikvm﹕ Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
12-05 23:29:02.664    7508-7508/? I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.app.Notification$Builder.setLocalOnly, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zza
12-05 23:29:02.664    7508-7508/? W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 238: Landroid/app/Notification$Builder;.setLocalOnly (Z)Landroid/app/Notification$Builder;
12-05 23:29:02.664    7508-7508/? D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x00c8
12-05 23:29:02.668    7508-7508/? I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.pm.PackageManager.getPackageInstaller, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zzj
12-05 23:29:02.668    7508-7508/? W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 533: Landroid/content/pm/PackageManager;.getPackageInstaller ()Landroid/content/pm/PackageInstaller;
12-05 23:29:02.668    7508-7508/? D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x000b
12-05 23:29:02.760    7508-7525/? I/GMPM﹕ App measurement is starting up
12-05 23:29:02.784    7508-7525/? E/GMPM﹕ getGoogleAppId failed with status: 10
12-05 23:29:02.820    7508-7525/? E/GMPM﹕ Uploading is not possible. App measurement disabled
12-05 23:29:02.940    7508-7512/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 258K, 14% free 3652K/4224K, paused 6ms+1ms, total 129ms
12-05 23:29:02.964    7508-7508/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 57K, 14% free 3689K/4264K, paused 4ms, total 4ms
12-05 23:29:02.968    7508-7508/? I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 6.413MB for 2628012-byte allocation
12-05 23:29:02.976    7508-7517/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 9% free 6255K/6832K, paused 7ms, total 7ms
12-05 23:29:02.984    7508-7512/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 9% free 6255K/6832K, paused 3ms+0ms, total 8ms
12-05 23:29:03.184    7508-7508/? D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_genymotion.so
12-05 23:29:03.184    7508-7508/? D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb8193208, tid 7508
12-05 23:29:03.196    7508-7508/com.example....... D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_genymotion.so
12-05 23:29:03.196    7508-7508/com.example......... D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_genymotion.so
12-05 23:29:03.344    7508-7508/com.example.........W/EGL_genymotion﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
12-05 23:29:03.344    7508-7508/com.example.........E/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from GradienCache
12-05 23:29:03.348    7508-7508/com.example......... E/OpenGLRenderer﹕ MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 16384
12-05 23:29:03.400    7508-7508/com.example.........E/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from Caches::initConstraints()
12-05 23:29:03.404    7508-7508/com.example......... E/OpenGLRenderer﹕ MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 16384
12-05 23:29:03.404    7508-7508/com.example..........D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
12-05 23:29:04.144    7508-7508/com.example.......... V/RenderScript﹕ 0xb81d1240 Launching thread(s), CPUs 4
12-05 23:29:08.044    7508-7508/com.example......... W/FileUtils﹕ Failed to chmod(/data/data/com.example........./databases/register.db): libcore.io.ErrnoException: chmod failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)
12-05 23:29:08.048    7508-7508/com.example.........r E/SQLiteLog﹕ (1) no such column: uname
12-05 23:29:08.048    7508-7508/com.example.. D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shut.......ting down VM
12-05 23:29:08.048    7508-7508/com.example......... W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa4cb3b20)
12-05 23:29:08.048    7508-7508/com.example...... E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example......, PID: 7508
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3823)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3818)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: uname (code 1): , while compiling: select uname, pass from register
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1314)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1253)
            at com.example........DatabaseHelper.searchPass(DatabaseHelper.java:69)
            at com.example........MainActivity.onButtonClick(MainActivity.java:39)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3818)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you post your logcat?

Comment: How can i know which part is needed  ? Is it all the red-text ?

Comment: by default logcat appears in the bottom section of the IDE.

Comment: NullPointerException: So one of the Views remains null because its id was not found in the xml. In line 42 of your code, you are trying to do something with this View.  You have to carefully compare all the id's.

Comment: how do you c line 42 ?

Comment: "at com.example........MainActivity.onButtonClick(MainActivity.java:42)"

Comment: I had tried many ways to fix it, but it doesn't work at all. TT

Answer (score -1):

I know your problem. 
Define these:

```
b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.blogin);
        b2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bsignup);
        ed1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.EVPassword);
```

In onCreate() method.
So the results will be:

```
   Button b1,b2;
    EditText ed1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.blogin);
            b2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bsignup);
            ed1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.EVPassword);
    }

     public void onButtonClick(View v){
                   if (v.getId() == R.id.blogin)
                {
                    EditText a = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ETmatrix);
                    String str = a.getText().toString();
                     ed1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.EVPassword);
                    String pass = ed1.getText().toString();
                    String password = helper.searchPass(str);

                    if(pass.equals(password))
                    {
                        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, HomePage.class);
                        i.putExtra("matrix", str);
                        startActivity(i);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast temp = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Matrix No. & Password does not match!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        temp.show();
                    }
                }
                if (v.getId() == R.id.bsignup )
                {
                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SignUp.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }



        }
        }
```

If that doesn't work, make sure the ID of each button/editText is correct (Java is case sensitive) and provide the logcat (When the app crashes, don't press "OK" on the device. Just copy and paste all the text in red in the logcat, and then you can press "ok"

Comment: hi, i already define the coding as u show, but it still the same ... wat more can i do ?

Comment: @Alice please provide a correct logcat: When your device is plugged in, and the app crashes, and it says "app is not responding", don't clilck "OK". Instead, go to your IDE and copy the text in red and paste it here. It should have `Caused by: error.example.error`

Comment: thanks a lot :) i figure out the problem , and it works

Comment: As said the logcat, it couldn't find an object you were looking for in the database. If you provided the logcat, I wouldn't have gotten a -1 xD

Comment: ya, after i know how to read the logcat, then only i know the problems is database XD